# Android studio Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

Tags: android-studio

I'm using android studio 1.5 and I have an error in gradle which is Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable' please see it in the picture....

[image]
drawable error